# decimal.Parse method

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I just found a very weird Bug in my c# code,

so there is a next:

when i´m trying to cast a object{string} to decimal like this :

```
item.ValiaFundo = row.IsNull("PL_FUNDO") ? 0 : decimal.Parse(row["PL_FUNDO"].ToString());
```

with the value of row = "2488.1987", it returns me 2488.1987 as supposed, but for some users returned value is 24881987.

i fixed it changing a type of object my database return to object{decimal}, like this :

```
item.ValiaFundo = row.IsNull("PL_FUNDO") ? 0 : (decimal)row["PL_FUNDO"];
```

that casts a value well for any user, and i just want to understand why that bug happens? What cause it? Does anyone have some ideas?

P.S.: server and users regional settings is the same for both cases.

Comment: What is your current culture?

Comment: Yes I'd guess that some of your users have a different culture to what you are expecting. (either the data is coming in as 2488,1987 or their culture is European.)

Comment: First thing to do: log the result of `row["PL_FUNDO"].ToString()` and also `123.45m.ToString()` (in close proximity).

Comment: My current culture is Portuguese ("pt-PT")

Comment: Probably off-topic to the crux of the question, but if the value in `row["PL_FUNDO"]` is _already_ stored as a `decimal` typed value, why bother converting to string and re-parse it? EDIT: Are you storing several different types in there (`string`, `double`, `int`) as well?

Comment: Put an if statement before this line to check the culture to be "pt-PT". Throw exception if it is not. Retry from both user's browsers if this is a web application. Note: this is for debugging, don't leave this in production code.

Comment: Chris, a row become from here : Decode(CM.COTACAO_MOEDA, 1, '', CM.valias_fiscais_up) PL_FUNDO , so the decode function makes it string object, then it was parsed to decimal whit a decimal.parse method, changing a row type to decimal object and casting to (decimal)row -> explicit cast fixed a problem, i just want to understand why the bug happens?

Comment: Maybe the core issue is in your `Decode` or database access layer. How do you _know_ the _"value of row = 2488.1987"_? Perhaps while the information in the database was being displayed to you as `2488.1987`, when running through the layers on a user's machine to eventually populate `row["PL_FUNDO"]` it applied some culture (or other tomfoolery) to modify the string before parsing.

Answer (score -1):

But, seems that data coming from server is already decimal in type.

It is a bad practice to go 
decimal --> string --> decimal.

As Jon Skeet pointed out (his answer disappeared) in some cultures comma is a decimal point. So when doing ToString() be careful about culture used.

Comment: I noticed that some answers disappeared. Strange. Among those from Jon Skeet.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why there's a problem with the string version. I deleted my answer because of hvd's comment, pointing out that it's already calling `ToString` using the current culture (so it should be able to parse it in the same culture).

Comment: Can it be that he changes Culture from UICulture ? So that culture in browser influences this conversion ?